# USB 2.0 devices not work on my mac only USB 3.0 Working

Tags: macos, usb, macbook-pro, usb-3, usb-2

I've a MacBook Pro 15" Unibody (Mid 2012) . The USB ports stopped working a while back; i.e.: the computer would no longer recognize any of USB devices. They are all USB 2.0 devices (external drive, Flash drive, etc.).
I did some testing and confirmed that it does indeed not recognize any USB 2.0 devices. the computer works just fine with any USB 3.0 devices that I've tested it with.
I've already tried all the usual quick fixes: reset SMC, reset PRAM, etc.
What’s the problem is ? Is it a hardware or software issue?

Comment: Have you tried plugging anything, phone, etc., to test if it can charge the device? There are a few devices out that you can find, some are a fair price. Try searching online for something like this: __USB 2.0 testing__

Comment: @vssher yes I plugged my phone and it not change but when I put external hard drive the drive is rotating

Comment: 3.0 USB are usually backward compatible with 2.0 devices, correct me if I'm wrong, you should be able to put your 2.0 hard drive into the 3.0 USB port and it should work.

Comment: @vssher Yes you’re right, As I said above when I put usb 3.0 device it recognized it but when I put usb 2.0 devices it not recognized

Comment: @vssher I mean in same port

Comment: Have you visited this page, It may help. Mac & Windows users.  "Here are eight things to try when your USB ports stop working" __What to Do When Your USB Ports Aren't Working__ https://www.lifewire.com/fix-usb-ports-4151908  See "Reset the System Management Controller (Mac)"

Comment: A very similar question cropped up only yesterday - though right now I can't find it. This ref suggests it's the port fuse links - https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/411486/weird:+USB+2.0+devices+not+recognized,+but+USB+3.0+devices+work+ok#answer621471

Comment: @vssher I did all these 8 things and Nothing changed

Comment: @Tetsujin I saw this but I don’t know what USB fuse is

Comment: You'd need a repair shop, perhaps even a new logic board.

Comment: Intel USB host chips have an internal switch that splits USB1.1/2 from USB3 devices. Also for USB2 and USB3 are different drivers used. Therefore it is reasonable that USB3 devices work where USB2 and 1.1 devices not.

Comment: @Robert Do you mean the problem in port themselves?

Comment: @iMustafa Note the port but the USB interface chip (which is AFAIK integrated into the Intel chipset). Alternatively it could be a driver defect. You could check that by booting a live Linux system via USB-stick if USB 1.1/2.0 devices work in the Linux live system it is a driver issue, otherwise it is most likely a hardware problem.